# Could be a namespace conflict (?) with login form and register form on the same page

Tags: pages, login, page-template, user-registration

I have created a "My Account" page template for WP 3.5.2 that displays certain custom data if a user is logged on. If not, the page displays a login form and a link that opens the register form in a fancybox, plus some other info for the app. The mechanics of the display work fine, and the rendered page passes the HTML syntax check with the typical exceptions in the head section.

**The problem:** I can get only one form to work at a time. If the login form is working, then the register form will not, and vice versa. That is, if I disable one the other works. When both are enabled and share the same value for input element attribute "name", e.g. "user_login", one will fail.

Both cases result in the same error message:

> undefined index user_login at line 530 in wp_login.php

I have tried creating unique ids on the input elements named 'user_login' but that did not cure the problem.

Sample of my code: http://pastebin.com/fevRMjHi

I would be most grateful if someone can suggest how to improve the code so the cause of  the problem is revealed. Of course a resolution outright would be very nice too.